# Uninstalling Anaconda Safely While Maintaining Pip Installs

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am unable to open the Anaconda Navigator after what I believe was trying to install nbviewer a couple of months ago. Whatever it was I was trying to install, I now get this error using any sort of conda command line:

[image: command line]

Would the installations I've made with pip be erased and overwritten if I uninstalled Anaconda? I really don't want to deal with software again, I'd rather pip install everything but at the same time, I still do not want to ruin my workflow with Jupyter notebook. I'm worried that uninstalling Anaconda will reset everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda is a package manager, just like pip. But conda also manages the python environments which are used to run your code. If you uninstall conda, it is very likely that it will uninstall all your current packages.

After re-installation, I recommend that you only use conda or pip for your packages but not both at the same time, and that you use conda for environment managing.

For each different kinds of projects, you should create a new python environment by running

```sh
conda create -n my-new-environment python=3 
#example
```

And only installing your packages with pip or conda.

This way each python environment is not polluted by the others and you have less risk to lose everything if one environment fails.

For more information of Python environments I recommend that you read the Python documentation on these subjects: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll read the link you posted and come back to this.